# How do I specify a custom URL path for a Jekyll collection?

Tags: jekyll

What if I want it to write the collection documents to /**m**/some_subdir/some_doc.html, for instance, but keep the collection name as `my_collection`?

[The documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) says:

> If you’d like Jekyll to create a public-facing, rendered version of each document in your collection, set the output key to true in your collection metadata in your `_config.yml`:

```
collections:
  my_collection:
    output: true
```

> This will produce a file for each document in the collection. For example, if you have `_my_collection/some_subdir/some_doc.md`, it will be rendered using Liquid and the Markdown converter of your choice and written out to /**my_collection**/some_subdir/some_doc.html.

But gives no option for configuring that.

Comment: This seems to add that feature, not sure if it's deployed by Github yet. Will try and get back: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/commit/5aefaa1c48b055061877fec1162aea144fdf8927

Comment: Update: adding `permalink: "m"` under `output: true` doesn't work (yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the following in your `_config.yml` file:

```
collections:
  my_collection:
    output: true
    permalink: /m/:path/
```

Simply `permalink: "m"` is not enough.

And you should update to Jekyll 2.1.0.